# Clicking link scroll to element then add a class to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html markup:

```
<div id="main">
    <p>some text</p>
    <a id="goto-notes" href="#">see notes</a>
    <p>some text...</p>
    <div id="notes">
        <p>notes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to scroll to the div#notes when clicking a#goto-notes then add a class (seen) to the div#notes to change styling. I use jquery scrollTo before to get it done easily but now I want to know how to do this without the scrollTo or any plugin. I've done some research and this is what I got so far.

```
$('#goto-notes').click(function(){
    $('#main').animate({scrollTop:500},'slow');
    $('#notes').addClass('seen');
});
```

at the moment div#notes is on 500px+ below the link.

1. How can I auto target it without specifying 500 similar to this method in scrollTo => $('#main').scrollTo('#notes'); because I may change the text on the top some time so div#notes is not anymore at 500.
2. also how to addclass only when the scrolling animate is finished, because if the text is very long when animate scroll reach the div#notes the styling is already finished (I put css transition to smoothly change styling), I want the user to see the transition.

Comment: can you pls add to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your css.

Comment: CSS is not needed for this answer...

Comment: Yes sorry I thought it's needed since OP mentioned css transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **How can I auto target it without specifying 500 ....** You just need to get the top position of the `#notes` like this: `$('#notes').position().top`
2. **also how to addclass only when the scrolling animate is finished...** You might wanna check the [animate() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) again, `animate()` has a `complete: function()` that is called once the animation is complete.

Here it is:

```
$('#goto-notes').click(function(){
    var n = $('#notes);

    $('#main').animate({
        scrollTop: n.position().top
    },{
        duration: 2000,
        complete: function(){
            n.addClass('seen');
        }
    });  
});
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/vv24R/)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to find the top value
2. Use the complete callback of [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Try

```
$('#goto-notes').click(function () {
    var $notes = $('#notes');
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $notes.offset().top
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $notes.addClass('seen');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZETA2/)

Comment: why animate $('body')? Sorry I not explained well. I have lots of contents inside body. This content is only on my div#main. When I click on your Fiddle it is not scrolling down